# phonegap 1.0 android facebook plugin login fail

Tags: java, android, facebook, cordova

i'm adding facebook post button to my app (phonegap 1.0), it seems that the only method to have this working is using the plugin here:
https://github.com/jos3000/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Facebook

But it's not working for me, first i saw in the log PluginManager not found, reading the docs it seems plugins are not being loaded like that anymore.

But the intent and dialog of facebook appear when calling
    window.plugins.facebook.authorize(appID, function(res){...})
I can see the facebook page being loaded but just after it finished the page automatically goes back with no response.

Anyboy has used succesfully this plugin??. actually the whole phonegap-plugin system seems to be very buggy... but i can't change the framework right now all the rest of the app is working.

Comment: I just started working with that plugin today. Did you add a line to res/xml/plugins.xml to reference FacebookAuth? What do you see in Logcat when things appear to go south?

Comment: And.. here's a newer Facebook PhoneGap plugin (and better? since Facebook SDK is a moving target): https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect.

Comment: Is it actually better? Or does it even work on Android? I've been trying for the past few days with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

At the end i managed to have it working by changing the Facebook authentication option in the java file, not using single sign on.
By the way i do **NOT** recommend phonegap... it seems to me the library is still full of bugs

Comment: i don't have problems with building my iPhone app in PhoneGap. Not sure about Android though. Can you mention some particular bugs if you say its "full" of bugs?

Answer (score 0):

I've only ever had very minor issues working with PhoneGap and iOS. Most we were able to find quick workarounds to resolve.

The issue is Android itself. I'm trying to avoid supporting it until Google steps in and enforces standards on every phone device manufacturer. Otherwise, you're guaranteeing yourself a swiss cheese codebase to deal with workarounds on every single device out there.